# Android studio error: duplicate attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm currently writing a page where the user has a timer for their exercise. There's a start button, a pause button, a resume button and a next exercise button. Whenever I try to move the resume button to another location, it gives me the following error:

> activity_exercise.xml:63: error: duplicate attribute.

The weird thing is, when the resume button is stacked on top of the start button, there is no error. As soon as I try to move it somewhere else, the app won't build.

Here is XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:timer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ExerciseActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startTimer"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="Start"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.892"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exerciseSet" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextExercise"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="Next"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.891"
    timer:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    timer:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.892"
    timer:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    timer:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exerciseSet" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pauseTimer"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="Pause"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.891"
    timer:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    timer:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.892"
    timer:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    timer:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exerciseSet" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/resumeTimer"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="Resume"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    timer:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    timer:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.892"
    timer:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    timer:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exerciseSet" />
```

Comment: Have you clean project after made changes in XML file

Comment: Yes, I have. I tried rebuilding it and it gives me the same error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix. It was something to do with timer:layout_constraint attributes. I had to rewrite all my constraints manually and it worked.